# Trying to fetch my data from the database but it has a problem fetching

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, row, echo

hi i am working on a travel and tour package management system where the admin creates a tour package using a form and after admin creates the package it will be displayed on the display page(where customers can view it) now i have this code for the itinerary (number of records to be displayed depends on how many itinerary records were created), but the problem is that the itinerary is not displaying on my display page . i have this code , and helping me find the problem will be a huge help :) thanks in advance :)

```
 $itineraries = $packageDatabase->query('SELECT * FROM tms_itinerary WHERE tourpackage_id = :tourpackage_id', 'array', array('tourpackage_id' => $_GET['id'])); 
    <?php 
        $section_count = 1; 
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($itineraries as $itinerary) : ?>
        <section <?php echo ( $section_count % 2 == 0 ) ? 'class="insurence-two-area pb-120"' : ''; ?>>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 insurence-left">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-one" src="<?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $itinerary['itinerary_image'] ); ?>" alt=""> <!--1st image in the itinerary section-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 insurence-right">

                        <h3 class="text-uppercase"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_first_date'] ?> - <?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_first_day'] ?></b></h3>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="list-wrap">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_first_description'] ?> </li>
                                </ul>

                        <hr>
                        <h3 class="text-uppercase"><b><?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_second_date'] ?> - <?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_second_day'] ?></b></h3>
                        <hr>
                         <div class="list-wrap">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <?php echo $itinerary['itinerary_second_description'] ?> </li>

                                <hr>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </section>
        <?php $section_count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: it is inside  the <?php tag . sorry it was located on the top of my program and i just put it near my problem codes :)

Comment: Show the entirety of your code, including database initialization (Remember to remove your password etc. before posting it here!)

Comment: do you get any errors ? you have checked the error.log ? well, not realy the problem, but <div class="container"> has no closing tag.

Comment: i already put the closing tag thanks for that :) but it is still not working.